# routing specific IP to ppp0 tunnel

Tags: router, iptables, routing

I feel I've struggled with this long enough and need some help.

I have a pptp tunnel and am trying to route destination traffic from 208.85.40.20 to the pptp tunnel (ppp0). (Keen observers may recognize the ip as being that of pandora.com).  I am doing all this configuration on a router... and I know it's not working successfully as traceroute yields nothing but astericks.

I've pasted relevant outputs below: (with some "security" editing to the addresses)

```
root@OpenWrt:~# ifconfig

br0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1A:92:BC:XX:XX
          inet addr:192.168.1.1  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:28185 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:24936 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:4894242 (4.6 MiB)  TX bytes:5941902 (5.6 MiB)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1A:92:BC:XX:XX
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING PROMISC MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:51829 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:56824 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:11490288 (10.9 MiB)  TX bytes:11857913 (11.3 MiB)
          Interrupt:4

eth2      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1A:92:BC:XX:XX
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING ALLMULTI MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:4 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:15426
          TX packets:9529 errors:21 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:423 (423.0 B)  TX bytes:596036 (582.0 KiB)
          Interrupt:2 Base address:0x2000

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:30 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:30 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:2300 (2.2 KiB)  TX bytes:2300 (2.2 KiB)

ppp0      Link encap:Point-Point Protocol
          inet addr:68.68.39.250  P-t-P:172.16.20.1  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1400  Metric:1
          RX packets:165 errors:2 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:68 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:3
          RX bytes:7006 (6.8 KiB)  TX bytes:3462 (3.3 KiB)

vlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1A:92:BC:XX:XX
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING ALLMULTI MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:28182 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:33813 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:5006544 (4.7 MiB)  TX bytes:6609774 (6.3 MiB)

vlan1     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1A:92:BC:XX:XX
          inet addr:173.183.111.3  Bcast:173.183.111.255  Mask:255.255.224.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:23653 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:23012 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:5522012 (5.2 MiB)  TX bytes:4982944 (4.7 MiB)

wds0.4915 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1A:92:BC:XX:XX
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wds0.4915 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1A:92:BC:XX:XX
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

---

```
root@OpenWrt:~# cat /etc/ppp/ip-up

iptables -A FORWARD -t filter -i br0 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -t filter -i ppp0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ppp0 -s 192.168.1.1/24 -d 0/0 -j MASQUERADE

iptables -A forwarding_rule -o ppp0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A forwarding_rule -i ppp0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A postrouting_rule -o ppp0 -j MASQUERADE
```

---

```
root@OpenWrt:~# route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
172.16.20.1     *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp0
208.85.40.20    *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp0
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br0
173.183.192.0   *               255.255.224.0   U     0      0        0 vlan1
default         d173-183-192-1. 0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 vlan1
default         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 br0
```

---

Any advice is greatly appreciated, I'm not too great with network but am pretty astute at learning ;-)

Answer (score 1):

you could do something like this for your ip-up script:

```
echo "route add 208.85.40.20 dev \$IFNAME" >> /etc/ppp/ip-up.local
chmod 755 /etc/ppp/ip-up.local
```

*EDIT*

I see your using openwrt; I don't think $IFNAME will resolve to ppp0,ppp1 etc.  The openwrt wiki hints at $INTERFACE in the ip-up  script:

```
echo "route add 208.85.40.20 dev \$INTERFACE" >> /etc/ppp/ip-up
```

*EDIT2*

Have you tried to manually add the route?

```
route add 208.85.40.20 dev ppp0
route add 208.85.40.50 dev ppp0
```

If so, does it show up in your routing table?
If it does, (I assume it does) then I suspect the problem is either in your firewall or on the other side of the ppp link.  You can verify with tcpdump - if you see traffic leaving the ppp0 interface but no return then it's likely the ppp peer.  If you see no traffic then check the iptables settings.

```
tcpdump -n ip host 208.85.40.20
```

insecure iptables for troubleshooting:

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -d 208.85.40.20 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -s 208.85.40.20 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD -s 208.85.40.20 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD -d 208.85.40.20 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -s 208.85.40.20 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -d 208.85.40.20 -j MASQUERADE
```

Comment: What you did yields what I had in my route table to begin with. traceroute'ing 208.85.40.20 afterwards does not return anything. =\

Comment: Eddy, thanks for the help to this point!

tcpdump -n ip host 208.85.40.20 -i eth0 captures ping request/replys before touching the route table.  Then after doing "route add 208.85.40.20 dev ppp0" and running tcpdump again with "tcpdump -n ip host 208.85.40.20 -i ppp0" it captures ping requests, but no reply back.  I've tried this with iptables flush, firewall stopped, your rules, etc. All the same result.  I assume if tcpdump shows it leaving the interface it is successfully passing the firewall? Maybe this is a ppp server issue, but its from strongvpn which is reputable.

Comment: Switched server, same results. HOWEVER, new discovery:: Initializing the tunnel with "pppd call strongvpn debug dump nodetach", then opening a new terminal and doing pinging/tracing on the 208.85.40.20 shows nothing being sent by pppd... I'd assume the daemon should be throwing out some sort of garble.

Comment: Some other facts:
I can ping 68.68.36.250 (this makes sense as its the IP of ppp0, but just stating).

I can't ping 172.16.20.1 (this to me doesn't make sense as I have 172.16.20.1 in the route table, and whilst it's the server address of the ppp server I'd figure it should be reachable for the tunnel to really be a tunnel....)

Comment: my guess is that your traffic is hitting the other end of the ppp tunnel; but your ppp0 ip address is not getting nat translation on the other side so the 172.16.20.1 server is coming back to you via its default gateway and getting lost.

Answer (score 0):

I've done a similar setup but using two routers and it works great. I set up the first router as 192.168.199.1 and set up the strongVPN router as 192.168.199.2. StrongVPN router has a static WAN address pointing to 192.168.199.1 as gateway. Primary router has routes added for addresses that it wants going out over the Tunnel. For Example 208.85.40.20, subnet 255.255.255.0, gateway 192.168.199.2. I use the /24 subnet because I figure that company may have a block of addresses for various servers. It works great and gives full speed on the bulk of network traffic and tunneled speed for services you want routed through your host country servers. I know this didn't specifically answer your original question but it is another way of getting there that I know works.